# A Regex to remove digits except for words starting with #

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I have some strings that can contain letters, numbers and '#' symbol.

I would like to remove digits except for the words that start with '#'

Here is an example:

```
"table9 dolv5e #10n #dec10 #nov8e 23 hello"
```

And the expected output is:

```
"table dolve #10n #dec10 #nov8e  hello"
```

How can I do this with regex, stringr or gsub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the wanted and replacing the unwanted with empty (non captured).

```
gsub("(#\\S+)|\\d+","\\1",x)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Gl5DHe/1) or [R demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRldBqSQxKSfVUiElP6fMNFVB2dAgT0E5JTXZ0EBBOS@/zCJVwchYISM1JydfiYsrvbg0SUNJQzkmJlhbsyYmJkVbSUcpJsZQSadC8/9/AA) (I have no experience with R)

My Answer is assuming, that there is always whitespace between `#foo bar #baz2`. If you have something like `#foo1,bar2:#baz3 4`, [use `\w`](https://regex101.com/r/Gl5DHe/2) (word character) instead of `\S` (non whitespace).

Answer (score 5):

You could split the string on spaces, remove digits from tokens if they don't start with '#' and paste back:

```
x <- "table9 dolv5e #10n #dec10 #nov8e 23 hello"
y <- unlist(strsplit(x, ' '))
paste(ifelse(startsWith(y, '#'), y, sub('\\d+', '', y)), collapse = ' ')
# output 
[1] "table dolve #10n #dec10 #nov8e  hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

You use gsub to remove digits, for example:

```
gsub("[0-9]","","table9")
"table"
```

And we can split your string using strsplit:

```
STRING = "table9 dolv5e #10n #dec10 #nov8e 23 hello"
strsplit(STRING," ")
[[1]]
[1] "table9" "dolv5e" "#10n"   "#dec10" "#nov8e" "23"     "hello"
```

We just need to iterate through STRING, with gsub, applying it only to elements that do not have "#"

```
STRING = unlist(strsplit(STRING," "))
no_hex = !grepl("#",STRING)
STRING[no_hex] = gsub("[0-9]","",STRING[no_hex])
paste(STRING,collapse=" ")
[1] "table dolve #10n #dec10 #nov8e  hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
unlisted_strings <- unlist(strsplit(X, "\\s+"))

Y <- paste0(na.omit(ifelse(grepl("[#]", unlisted_strings),

                           unlisted_strings,

                           gsub("\\d+", "", unlisted_strings))), collapse = " ")

Y
```

Data:

```
X <- as.character("table9 dolv5e #10n #dec10 #nov8e 23 hello")
```

Comment: this doesn't give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
INPUT = "table9 dolv5e #10n #dec10 #nov8e 23 hello";
OUTPUT = INPUT.match(/[^#\d]+(#\w+|[A-Za-Z]+\w*)/gi).join('');
```

You can remove flags `i`, cause it was case insensitive

Use this pattern: `[^#\d]+(#\w+|[A-Za-Z]+\w*)`

`[^#\d]+`           = character start with no # and digits 
`#\w+`              = find # followed by digit or letter
`[A-Za-z]+\w*` = find letter followed by letter and/or number
          ^
          |
You can change this with `\D+\S*` =  find any character not just when the first is letter and not just followed by letter and/or number.
I am not put as `\w+\w*` cause `\w` same as = `[\w\d]`.

I tried the code in JavaScript and it work.
If you want match not only followed by letter you can use code